# Using Average Function in Table layout with Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to create a table for feedback form. I have 35 spinners in that table layout. And I am trying to calculate the average of the every feedback entry in the text view with 7 columns and 6 rows.

Do I actually need to write the code for all 35 spinner's to calculate the average of the table columns and rows. Can we pass the name of the spinner as a parameter, or is there any other way? I am tired of writing code for 35 spinner.

Following is the code one spinner.

```
  s_11.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // Column Spinner
            if(s_12.getSelectedItemId()==5) {
                c2=0;
            }
            else{
                c2 = Integer.parseInt(s_12.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }
            //----------------------------------------------------------
            if(s_13.getSelectedItemId()==5) {
                c3=0;
            }
            else {

                c3 = Integer.parseInt(s_13.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }
            //-----------------------------------------------------------
            if(s_14.getSelectedItemId()==5) {
                c4=0;
            }
            else{
                c4 = (Integer.parseInt(s_14.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            }
            //-----------------------------------------------------------
            if(s_15.getSelectedItemId()==5) {
                c5=0;
            }
            else{
                c5 = (Integer.parseInt(s_15.getSelectedItem().toString()));

            }
            //-----------------------------------------------------------

            if(s_16.getSelectedItemId()==5) {
                c6=0;
            }
            else {
                c6 = (Integer.parseInt(s_16.getSelectedItem().toString()));

            }
            //-----------------------------------------------------------
            if(s_17.getSelectedItemId()==5) {
                c7=0;
            }
            else{
                c7 = (Integer.parseInt(s_17.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            }

            //ROW Spinner

            if(s_21.getSelectedItemId()==5) {
                r2=0;
            }
            else {
                r2 = (Integer.parseInt(s_21.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            }
            //-----------------------------------------------------------
            if(s_31.getSelectedItemId()==5) {
                r3=0;
            }
            else{
                r3 = (Integer.parseInt(s_31.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            }
            //-----------------------------------------------------------
            if(s_41.getSelectedItemId()==5) {
                r4=0;
            }
            else{
                r4 = (Integer.parseInt(s_41.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            }

            if(s_51.getSelectedItemId()==5) {
                r5=0;
            }
            else{
                r5 = (Integer.parseInt(s_51.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            }

            if(s_61.getSelectedItemId()==5){
                r6=0;
            }
            else{
                r6=(Integer.parseInt(s_61.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            }


            //Selected Spinner
            if(s_11.getSelectedItemId()==5){
                SelRating=0;
            }
            else{
                s_11.setSelection(position);
                SelRating=(Integer.parseInt(s_11.getSelectedItem().toString()));

            }
            average avg=new average();
            int count=avg.calAvg(SelRating,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6);
            Log.d("Simple","Value: "+ new Integer(count).toString());
            //Average
            float ResC=0;
            ResC=(c2 + c3 + c4 + c5 + c6 + c7 + SelRating)/count;

            float ResR=0;
            ResR=(SelRating + r2 + r3 + r4 + r5 )/count;

            Overall_1.setText(Float.toString(ResC));
            Alliance_R7.setText(Float.toString(ResR));


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"All Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Please Help!! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean "average of feedback entry"? Please elaborate on that.

Comment: Consider I have to give rating to a teacher regarding the various entities like "Was content understandable", "Does lecturer meet your expectation?", "Was teaching more focused ". And the rating of such entities is measured in numbers like "1,2,3,4,5". @longwalker Average of feedback entry means average of these entities.